# Skimage ValueError: total size of new array must be unchanged

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, scikit-image, scikits

I am trying to use skimage.color separate_stains in an HE deconvolution.

```
i_hdx = separate_stains(ihc, conv_matrix)
```

returning an error `ValueError: total size of new array must be unchanged`

Is there an issue with the version of skimage.color (0.10.0), something with `np.reshape`, or a separate issue?

EDIT: The size of the image seems to play a part in getting an error, which leads me to believe it could be a numpy issue.

```
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/skimage/color/colorconv.py", line 1131, in separate_stains
stains = np.dot(np.reshape(-np.log(rgb), (-1, 3)), conv_matrix)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/fromnumeric.py", line 221, in reshape
return reshape(newshape, order=order)
```

Comment: Can you post more of your actual code and the whole traceback?

Comment: Can you post the shape of your data? `ihc.shape, conv_matrix.shape`.